# Tying a users google account to a phone which relies on a WebService

Tags: android, web-services, google-account

I'm currently working on an Android App / Web Service / Desktop app that syncs things like data and allows some bidirectional control. I knew that it wouldn't be simple but I've run into a snag that I can't seem to figure out: I want a  user's phone to be tied to their google account so that the server can recognize it and send the data to the right PC. I don't want to build my own users database because it seems redundant since the phone is already connected with a Google account. Thinking about this however, what if a user has multiple Android phones on the same account, how do I distinguish?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

But [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager) might help you for tying the app to user's google account.

> Thinking about this however, what if a user has multiple Android phones on the same account, how do I distinguish?

Why do you have to distinguish multiple phones? From my understanding of your problem, If users choose the same account on multiple devices then it should be treated identical.